# Create content types on the fly in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

One of our website requirements is to have a content type that let's you decide on the total amount of content types on the fly.

For instance, if I specify a number 10, then it ought to generate the content types consecutively,  one of type 'textarea' and another of type 'radio' are created 10 times.

essentially to break it programmatically, it will create:

```
<?php
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
echo "<input type = 'textarea'></input>";
echo "<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>";
} 
?>
```

This is pretty straightforward if I was dabbling with simple PHP files, but with Drupal 7's content types (CCK), it is posing a bigger challenge than what it ought to be IMHO. I have tried exploring modules that let you create content types on the fly and considered creating a custom content type programmatically which seems like another challenge altogether.

I am curious if anybody has an alternative for this and has dabbled with this challenge before. Your answers are most appreciated.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create content dynamic types in drupal 7 you will need to follow the below process:

Updated *

1) Create a menu path using hook_menu() which uses drupal_get_form(). This will allow you to gather all data for your users input for the dynamic content creation.

Example:

```
$items['newpost'] = array(
'title' => 'Create Post',
'description' => 'The main noticeboard',
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('customvishal_create_content'),
'access callback' => TRUE,
);
return $items;
```

2) Then use:

```
function customvishal_create_content($form, &$form_submit) // To create your form on that page
function customvishal_create_content_validate($form, &$form_state) // for any kind of validation


function customvishal_create_content_submit($form, &$form_state)
```

- In this function you can submit the values into your new content type.
- Here is where you will call the below functions.

3) Create an array which will hold the meta data about your content type.

```
// Define the node type.
$mystuff = array(
'type' => 'mystuff',
'name' => $t('my new Stuff'),
'base' => 'node_content',
'description' => $t('This is an example node type.'),
'body_label' => $t('Content')
 );

 // Set defaults.
$content_type = node_type_set_defaults($mystuff);
```

4) use node_type_save() to save/declare your content type.

```
node_type_save($content_type);
```

5) Create fields and then attach to your content type.

```
foreach (_mystuff_installed_fields() as $field) {
field_create_field($field);
}

// Create instances of fields.
foreach (_mystuff_installed_instances() as $instance) {
$instance['entity_type'] = 'node';
$instance['bundle'] = $mystuff['type'];
field_create_instance($instance);
}
```

Comment: Vishal, thanks for the help, but this does not quite address the challenge I am facing. The idea is to create dynamic content types, creating the content type is not the challenge here.

Comment: the key is using durpal_get_forms() I have explained further in the post.